# Create table and use it - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm facing a very strange thing using CI,

I'm using the DBforge class to create a table, All is well and the table is indeed created on my DB.

However, When I attempt to use the newly created table(insert, check if exists etc.) I get nowhere.
given the following simple code : (both functions are inside a model)

```
function create_modules_table($tablename)
{
            $fields = array(
            'module_name' => array(
                    'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint' => '100'
            ),
            'status' => array(
                    'type' =>'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint' => '100'
            ),

    );
    $this->dbforge->add_key('module_name', TRUE);
    $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
    return $this->dbforge->create_table($tablename);
}
```

Followed by a

```
function table_exists($table)
{
    return $this->db->table_exists($table);
}
```

If I run

```
$this->create_modules_table('table');
$reply = $this->table_exists('table');
```

It turns out that `$reply is returning false`.

I check my DB - The table sure is there, 100% working fine.

So i run the code again, without deleting the table from the DB, `now the reply is true`.

The first run always fails the check, As if CI isn't aware that something changed in the DB. **Can anyone shed light on what's going on here? **

Comment: Maybe DBForge or the database library is caching a list of tables and it's not being updated when you create the table?

Comment: Yea i thought the same thing, nothing on the docs though.. makes it a bit silly as it makes it hard to use it for table creation.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the solution in .[This link](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/15096/dbforge-create_table_does_not_update_db-data_cachetable_names.)

It is a CI Bug that do not update data_cache after creating a new table by DB_forge.